# How to implement a json response for sencha touch?

Tags: php, sencha-touch-2, json

I am implementing a app with a login-screen. and I don't know how i should implement the json response for sencha touch.

this is my login.js

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: 'http://localhost/alt/FIFA-Europaliga/admin/index.php?page=login_try_app',
method: 'post',
params: {
    login: Ext.getCmp('username').getValue(),
    password: Ext.getCmp('passwort').getValue(),
},
failure: function (response) {
    var loginResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    if (loginResponse.success === "false") {
        alert('fail');
    }
},
success: function (response) {
    //console.log(response);
    //console.log(response.responseText);

    var loginResponse = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
    if (loginResponse.success === "true") {
        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem("mainview",{
            type: "pop",
            direction: "left"
        });
    }
},

});
```

and this is my login_try.php

```
<?php

$result = "{'success':false}";

if (count($_POST) > 0) {
$_POST = $sys->db->sql_filter($_POST);
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$user = new User($login, $password);

if ($user->login($sys->db)) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    $result = "{'success':true}";
} else {
    $result = "{'success':false}";
}
 } else {
$result = "{'success':false}";
 }

echo $result;
 echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

now I get the full login.php file from the server as response. and I want only a true or false

Can you help me?

Thank you!
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Probably `'` issue. Try using array and json_encode(). Do not echo $result as is.

```
// default false
$result = array('success' => false);
//...

    $result['success'] = true;
} 

echo json_encode($result);
```

And there is no reason to make `success` `false` in the middle of the code (default false already).

Comment: I still get the whole login page as respone.

Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TrackMyRun </title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/global.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../system/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../system/js/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../system/js/countdown.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" ....